# typescript how to get a type from ReturnType which return multiple different type value return

Tags: typescript

```
function Hoge() {
  ...
  // A and B, both of them are different complicated object value(type).
  return {A, B}
}
```

I want to describe only `A` type on below example.
**How do I get type of only `A` or `B` using `ReturnType<T>`**

```
const A: ReturnType<typeof Hoge>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), you can get the type of the property `A` from the return type.

```
const A: ReturnType<typeof Hoge>['A']
```